# Сборка проекта typescript + node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

Столкнулся со следующей загвоздкой: из-за одного пакета, а именно "[file-type](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type)", приходится backend писать esm синтаксисом. Вот tsconfig.json файл:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  }
}
```

При этом подходе возникло 2 проблемы:

1. Если попытаться импортировать собственную функцию - в таком случае команда ts-node-esm завершается с ошибкой. Говорит, что не может найти импортируемый файл.
   *!При этом импортировать сторонние пакеты/библиотеки получается без проблем.(ошибку не выдает в таком случае)*

```
PS C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\backend> ts-node-esm ./src/app.ts
C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366
    throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(                                                                         
          ^                                                                                                 
CustomError: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\backend\src\types' imported from C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\backend\src\app.ts
    at finalizeResolution (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:366:11)                                                                                       
    at moduleResolve (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:801:10)                                                                                            
    at Object.defaultResolve (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\dist-raw\node-internal-modules-esm-resolve.js:912:11)                                                                                    
    at C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:218:35                                                                                                                                               
    at entrypointFallback (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:168:34)                                                                                                                          
    at C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:217:14                                                                                                                                               
    at addShortCircuitFlag (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:409:21)                                                                                                                         
    at resolve (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:197:12)                                                                                                                                     
    at resolve (C:\Users\Владимир\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\child\child-loader.ts:15:39)                                                                                                                       
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
```

2. При попытке скомпилировать файлы, с помощью команды tsc - файлы компилируются вроде бы без проблем(в том числе собственные модули), однако в консоль выползает ряд ошибок следующего вида:

```
PS C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Programming\Frontend\Projects\file sharing\backend> npx tsc
node_modules/peek-readable/lib/StreamReader.d.ts:1:23 - error TS1452: 'resolution-mode' assertions are only supported when `moduleResolution` is `node16` or `nodenext`.

1 /// <reference types="node" resolution-mode="require"/>
                        ~~~~

node_modules/strtok3/lib/core.d.ts:1:23 - error TS1452: 'resolution-mode' assertions are only supported when `moduleResolution` is `node16` or `nodenext`.

1 /// <reference types="node" resolution-mode="require"/>


// и так далее
```

Отсюда вытекают 2 вопроса:

1. Можно ли как-то пакет file-type импортировать не с помощью import, а с помощью require, чтобы автоматом избавиться от остальных ошибок?
2. Если нельзя, то как справиться с вышеупомянутыми проблемами?

Comment: Попробуй `tsx` раннер, в нём все варианты модулей кросс-совместимы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Используй версию `file-type@^16`.
`file-type` стал pure-ESM как BREAKING CHANGE в 17.0.0 https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/releases?page=2

b) Используй раннер [tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx), в нём [можно смешивать разные виды модулей](https://github.com/privatenumber/ts-runtime-comparison)

с) Переведи свой package на ESM, см. [Pure ESM package](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c)